# Do we ask a waiter if we could have or get?

Tags: differences, word-usage

I have noticed a tendency among the younger generation, when ordering in a pub or restaurant, to say 'Please could I get beer-battered cod and chips', whereas I would and do say 'Please could I have beer-battered cod...'.

Is 'get' nowadays acceptable English, even in a very posh restaurant?  I mean one where you wouldn't order cod and chips!

Comment: *Get the chateaubriand. It's marvelous!*

Comment: @bib That makes it sound as if I have to rope the animal, slaughter it, butcher it and cook it!

Comment: And think how much more we will enjoy it! Kidding aside, I think this is heard regularly at all levels of eating establishments in the US. *Getting something to eat* is a stock phrase, while *having ...* not so much.

Comment: If you want to sound even more "posh" (daft idea, imho) you could always go for *"I'll **take** the lobster bisque [my good man]"*.

Comment: Reminds me of the Peter Sellers sketch where he orders the most elaborate meal from a waiter,something like, 'sturgeon... tournedos rossini... a good stilton...followed by the crepes flambe.' 'wine?' 'er... yes please,  a good Bordeaux with the main course and Cockburns with the cheese. 'Now my good man, please put that lot on the bill and bring me the seven and sixpenny businessman's lunch!'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's incorrect at all. It may be irregular or unconventional where you're from, but if we consider "to get" typically means "to come into possession of" or "to attain," we have the following sentences:

> Please could I come into the possession of beer-battered cod and chips?
>
> Please could I attain beer-battered cod and chips?

In both cases, it not assumed that **I** will be the person bringing this state about; The waiter will undoubtedly be the one "getting" the food in an active sense. Once given to me, I have got it.

With @WS2's comment in mind, I wanted to dive into this a bit further. I'm not saying it *should* be used, but that it *could* be used depending on the understood definition. I have heard the following in **spoken** conversation and do not hesitate a bit.

> I told you already, the bills will get paid.
>
> Regardless, this project will get done.
>
> Can I get an "Amen!"

They may be shoddy sentences, but the bill doesn't mail itself along with a check, the project doesn't spend sleepless nights finishing itself, and the zealot will not run and grab an "Amen!" from the audience. "Get" in these cases is to represent a completed action, state of being, or a state of possession.

In @WS2's example, where a wife asks, "Can **you** get some bread," it is implied that "get" is an active verb to be performed by the subject, the obliging husband. But in a restaurant, "Can **I** get the burger" merely suggests an action to be performed to bring me into possession of a burger. It is safely assumed from previous experience that the waiter will in fact be getting the burger, but it is not explicitly stated.

If we take "get" to mean "to acquire," then I agree "have" would be preferred in this case. But I would tend, especially in spoken conversation in a restaurant, to assume to aforementioned definition regarding possession, regardless of the means of acquisition.

Note: A quick search shows this construction has been in (though admittedly rare) use since 1852. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=CUI_AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA87&dq=%22can%20I%20get%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i77WUqWDL4a7oQTt1ICQAg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22can%20I%20get%22&f=false).

Comment: But 'get' is an active verb (nothing to do with active/passive voice here), it implies an action on the part of the getter. My wife asks me if I can go and 'get' some bread from the shop. That involves my putting my outdoor clothes on, walking to the shop, picking up the bread, paying for it, discussing the latest cricketing debacle with the Indian bloke on the till, and walking home. That is what 'get' amounted to in 'getting bread'. So when I ask the waiter if I can 'get' the halibut, will ne expect me to go and catch it? All I want is to 'have' it.

Comment: @WS2 I've made some edits to my post to attempt answering your question. You and the waiter performed the act of "getting" the bread and meal respectively. But, at the end of these actions, your wife "gets" or "has" the bread and I "get" or "have" the meal. I'm curious if this is at all convincing to you?

Comment: well done! What we are arguing over is the meaning of 'get'. I just looked in the OED and, as you might expect, the entry is vast. Simply 'to obtain' forms the essence of various of the meanings.  But I did a word search on each of 'restaurant', 'waiter', 'food', 'meal', 'order' and could find nothing that referred to the matter under discussion. So my conclusion would be that whilst 'get' probably does the job grammatically, there is no recorded tradition, so far as the OED is concerned, of 'getting' food from a waiter. So I'm happy to call a truce on that, if you are.

Comment: @WS2 I certainly am!

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the phrase "can I get..." seems to be more common among people who aren't accustomed to being served. They may find it weird to plainly ask "can I have...", which is a more direct way of asking for service. So instead, they phrase it in a way that sounds like they can serve themselves.

Or perhaps, being the younger generation, they think the "can I have..." phrase sounds overly proper. And they think, "that's how old people say it".

Answer (score 0):

This may be increasingly common amongst the younger generation (of which I am one, technically ;-) but they're nonetheless guilty of misuse.

I usually stop myself from committing the same offence by thinking about the classic wind-up where Person A says, "please can I have *<xyz>*", to which Person B says "of course you can..." then does nothing, infuriating the first person.

Person A then says, "please ***may*** I have <xyz>?" to which Person B says, "of course!" and gives it to them.

Ultimately, if you've got the money to pay the menu, they probably they don't mind how you order.

Comment: Thank you. I will pass on your remarks to my daughter and son who are respectively 8 and 4 years your senior, and ought to know better.

Comment: Haha! And remember, there's always the cane...

Answer (score 0):

Since "get" is a verb, I'd think the most correct form for using it in this context would be "Please get me the beer-battered Cod". Because the person making the order will not actually retrieve the food themselves, they are asking the waiter or waitress to do that for them.

I've often tried to mirror the question that the server asks when they come to take my order:

- "What will you have?", "I'll have the squid please.";
- "What would you   like?", "I'd like a winning lottery ticket - I'd like to order the
  squid please.";
- "What can I get for you, hon?", "Please get me the Squid, thanks."

The mirroring can work well in "posh" settings - unless the other person has already butchered the language. But even then, it gives you the chance to right it.